# How to kill the duck

Tags: support, feature-request

There is a duck on the homepage. It is a bright colour and does not scroll with the page, hence it is a hideous eyesore and needs to be removed from my sight.

I clicked on it, hoping a close option would appear. I was instead presented with a dialog asking if I had a microphone. Naturally I selected "no", but it activated my microphone and started listening anyway.

The duck is evil. I wish it to be gone immediately. Please tell me how.

(Well, I've killed it with an adblocker now, so fair enough. I'm all for april fools jokes, and yes, you got me - mostly through the not-so-clever trick of doing it *in March* - but do you have to make it so difficult to dismiss the thing once we've got the joke?)

Comment: I thought it was an early April fool's joke! Is it really here to stay?

Comment: Oh, I didn't realise, that makes sense. It's still the 31st here in Japan. I will simply avoid the site for the next 24 hours. (Actually I guess it's still the 31st everywhere.)

Comment: Ah, you need to just let it go on for a while. After a minute it'll give you the option to remove it.

Comment: I think it appeared at about 11 a.m. UK time, which is 00:00 on 1st April in the UTC+14 time zone. So it appeared as soon as it was 1st April somewhere (Kiribati?).

Comment: You can kill it  - I think the duck will ask you something like if you hate it. If you answer "yes I hate you", then the duck (or rather the drake) will be gone.

Comment: @Shing yeah, I read that also. But that requires me to click on the duck and go through the dialogue (which, I understand, involves my computer making a noise), and only then can I select the option --- and I have to do that all over again for every site I visit. It's unreasonable, and it's more time consuming than just blocking the relevant elements.

Comment: Is it really that obtrusive? I mean, even with me knowing about this duck through this post, it still took me like 10 minutes to actually notice it. And even then, going back to the [review queue](https://physics.stackexchange.com/review), it was gone from my periphery.

Comment: @KyleKanos for me, yes it is. YMMV of course.

Answer (score 4):

[This mother meta post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/308570/263383) describe how to tell the duck you hate it so it goes away. From [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/308574/263383):

> There is an option to remove this duck **after** [emphasis mine] it quacks once. Click on "I hate this duck". It understands and disappears.

If you have a problem with the duck growing attached to you and coming back after a while, see the other answers there.

Comment: Q: _What is an up, a down or a strange?_ A: _Quack!_

Comment: Are we sure this is an April Fools thing and not the first shot in a tex.se invasion of the entire network?